# Cassandra database project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, cassandra, schema

I currently use a Database Project in Visual Studio to track SQL Server schema changes and to easily create scripts to deploy these changes to any environment prior to code deployment.

I am investigating Cassandra for some research projects and was wondering if there is anything similar. I would like to be able to track schema changes and easily to deploy this to whatever environment it is needed in.

Is this even feasible in the way Cassandra is supposed to be used? For instance if I wanted some column per user like, SomeUserInfo_User_10, does the code see if that column is already defined prior to usage? I can see the table columns and secondary indexes eventually becoming a no man's land and forgotten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing I've seen to what you describe is a GUI tool called Datastax DevCenter.  It lets you connect to different Cassandra clusters, explore and modify their schemas, create/save/execute CQL scripts, view query results and query traces.  It looks like it is built on top of the Eclipse codebase.  You can see details of how tables are defined, including secondary indexes with it.

You could do all the same things from a command line and cqlsh, but if you like a GUI interface, this might be worth checking out.

You can download it from [here](http://www.datastax.com/download-ops-dev#DataStax_DevCenter).

They also have another GUI called OpsCenter which I think is more for monitoring clusters, but I haven't tried that one.